# How to plot large Y values from a file in python?

Tags: python, plot, graphics

I have +8000 values that I need to plot in python. I tried several snippets that I found but none worked.
My file (.dat) has the following structure :

```
  -7.1441700e-01
  -5.5069000e-01
  -4.5883200e-01
  -5.5877700e-01
  -5.7281500e-01
  -7.2219800e-01
  -4.0725700e-01
  -8.7051400e-01
  -1.1273190e+00
  -1.0572810e+00
  -9.7869900e-01
  -9.4284100e-01
  -8.7326000e-01
  -8.7219200e-01
  -7.1533200e-01
  -5.2352900e-01
  -4.7027600e-01 ....
```

My goal is to obtain something like this:

[image]

But for some reason I'm not getting the same result. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using numpy and matplotlib, you should be able to load the data directly into a numpy array and then plot that:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('filename.dat')
plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

If this does not work, post the error messages you are receiving.

Comment: goddam it worked :D
Im new at python, sorry for the rookie mistake.
Is there a way to change the gap between X values?
here's the result https://ibb.co/MVYbJrY

Comment: No worries. If you want to define the x values, you can use `plt.plot(x_data, y_data)`, or if all of the data is saved in one file: `plt.plot(data[0,:], data[1,:])` (assuming x data is in the first column and y data in the second)